# Create vector layers in sql in spatialite db with PyQGIS / QtSql

Tags: pyqgis, sql, geometry, spatialite, create

I have a vector layer in a spatialite DB structured as follows:

[image]

In PyQGIS I try to create a derived vector layer from this like

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSPATIALITE')
db.setDatabaseName('C:\\tmp\\test.sqlite')
db.open()
q = QSqlQuery('create table nat2000_hetzles_11 as select * from nat2000_hetzles where maes_2_06 = 11', db)
q._exec()
```

(note that the query is just a simple example, as a matter of fact it might consist of far more complicated conditions, joins, etc.)

The table is created but I'm facing some issues. `GEOMETRY` column is empty and QGIS just recognizes the result as a table (not vector layer).

The latter can be fixed by registering the geometry column in `geometry_columns` table like

```
insert into geometry_columns values ('nat2000_hetzles_11', 'geometry', 3, 2, 31468, 0)
```

The `GEOMETRY` seems to need special treatmant, but I could not figure out what.

How is the `GEOMETRY` created in statements like `create my_vec as select * from my_source_vec where...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the `geometry_columns` table is not a good idea.

The table should be created from scratch like

```
create table if not exists nat2000_hetzles_11 (
    ogc_fid integer not null primary key autoincrement,
    uid integer not null,
    maes_4_06 integer not null)
```

and adding a geometry column by (cp. https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.0/spatialite-sql-2.3.0.html#p16)

```
select addgeometrycolumn('nat2000_hetzles_11', 'geometry', 31468, 'POLYGON', 2, 1)
```

and then `insert`ing the selection in the newly created table

```
insert into nat2000_hetzles_11 (uid, maes_4_06, geometry)
select uid, maes_4_06, geometry
from nat2000_hetzles
where maes_2_06 = 11
```

resulting in

[image]